# Obtaining the count of occurences of a value in one table in two columns of second table

Tags: mysql

I would really love some help in finding the most efficient MySQL query for the scenario I have laid out below. I have added a small snippet of data as an example, but the data for the query will be vast and will only inflate over time, hence the reason I would really like to find the most efficient method of getting to the expected result. Thanks for reading, I hope someone can clarify this for me.

TABLE NAME employees

```
+-------------+---------------+
| employee_id | employee_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|     0000001 | James         |
|     0000002 | David         |
|     0000003 | Mark          |
|     0000004 | Gemma         |
|     0000005 | Hayley        |
|     0000006 | Sunil         |
+-------------+---------------+
```

TABLE NAME employees_orders

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
| order_id | Lead_generated_by   | sale_generated_by |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
|    00001 | James               | David             |
|    00002 | Mark                | Gemma             |
|    00003 | Hayley              | David             |
|    00004 | James               | Mark              |
|    00005 | Gemma               | Hayley            |
|    00006 | Sunil               | Mark              |
|    00007 | David               | James             |
|    00008 | Hayley              | Sunil             |
|    00009 | Gemma               | James             |
|    00010 | Hayley              | David             |
+----------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Expected Result

```
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| employee_name | leads_generated | sales_generated |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| James         |               2 |               2 |
| David         |               1 |               3 |
| Mark          |               1 |               2 |
| Gemma         |               2 |               1 |
| Hayley        |               3 |               1 |
| Sunil         |               1 |               1 |
+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
SELECT
        e.employee_name,
        coalesce(l.count,0) AS leads_generated,
        coalesce(s.count,0) AS sales_generated
    FROM
        employees e
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Lead_generated_by as employee_name, count(*) AS count FROM employees_orders GROUP BY 1 ) l ON ( e.employee_name = l.employee_name )
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT sale_generated_by as employee_name, count(*) AS count FROM employees_orders GROUP BY 1 ) s ON ( e.employee_name = s.employee_name )
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

That said, a few suggestions:

- Consider using employee_id in place of character-based `_generated_by` fields for better performance.
- Take steps to ensure that all employees are listed in `employees`, which `employee_id` use can help with (e.g., with foreign key constraints).
- Be aware that the above query assumes that there are no names in employee_name that are not in `employees`.

Comment: ahi324, thank you for your contribution. I have basically inherited the data as it is now, I know its not ideal and I'm looking to convert the two values in the second table from names to the employees ID. I will try your suggestion now. Again, thank you for your time.